# Bluescreen after upgrading RAM

Tags: memory, bsod, asus-laptop

I have an ASUS M409DAi with 4GB DDR4 RAM (2400mhz clock speed) and I want to upgrade it by adding a 4GB Kingston DDR4 RAM DIMM with the same clock speed; however, after installation, my laptop shows a blue screen (UEFI shows 8019MB of RAM).

- I watched videos showing the upgrade on similar laptops with the exact same type of RAM from a different brand.

-The specs of my ram that i bought is DDR4, 2400MHz, Non-ECC, CL17, 1.2V, Unbuffered, SODIMM, 1R, 4Gbit

-It was booted to windows and work fine, but as soon as im opening app that memory hungry it immediatly goes to BSOD with detail : memory management

How do I troubleshoot this (I cannot return the RAM module)? 
Is it compatibility or a problem with the module?

Comment: Does POST complete and have you run the built-in hardware diagnostics _(usually accessible via the UEFI settings or UEFI boot options)_? Is the RAM the correct type (SODIMM, SDRAM, ECC, non-ECC, unbuffered, buffered, etc.)? For anyone to provide a definitive answer, please edit your question, adding the full Kingston model number. Certain laptop manufacturers lock their laptops to specific brands and model numbers via an allowed hardware list in UEFI, with ASUS being one of those OEMs _(doesn't mean your laptop is affected, but is something you may want to verify)_.

Comment: How do i know if my laptop need ECC or non-ECC, unbuffered or buffered. Cause i already check my ram that i bought it was non-ECC and unbuffered. And how can i open this hardware list in uefi

Comment: It's likely non-ECC, as the only laptops I'm aware that use ECC RAM are Macs. As to Unbuffered/Buffered and SODIMM/SDRAM, go to Kingston's or Crucial's website and look up your laptop or google the part number on the DIMM that came with the laptop. Also, the Kingston DIMM's model number is preferable.

Comment: Yeahh, from the serial number i already got that info from kingstone website.. and for that crucial website, it doesnt recognize my laptop.. its not listed there yet i guess

Comment: Don't know why no one else has said this - it sounds to me like your RAM is faulty, and that its nothing to do with the type of memory you bought.  I would run a memory burn-in test.

Comment: @davidgo What does it mean by faulty? And how can i run memory burn-in cause it immediately goes to BSOD now once it got to sign in.

Comment: Run memtest off a bootable USB disk - https://www.memtest86.com/tech_creating-window.html

Comment: @davidgo I suggested that in the first sentence in the first comment _("...have you run the built-in hardware diagnostics usually accessible via the UEFI settings or UEFI boot options...")_. The built-in diagnostics includes a short and long RAM test, memtest not required _(all laptops built since at least 2010 include BIOS or UEFI built-in hardware diagnostics)_